# CSS transitions not happening for pseudoelement when elements are removed from div

Tags: css, css-transitions

I was playing around with a pre-made Svelte Tree-view and decided to add some rule lines and make it monospace like vscode's, as shown in this link https://svelte.dev/repl/5dcfce933e3b457d9d5fd19b66a41a37?version=3.23.2

[image: Tree view of United States States as well as a bunch of amusement parks.]

I have made the rule line into a `::before` psuedo-element and made it so that the line is perfectly in between the angle brackets as well. I wanted to make it so when opening and closing the tree, the rule lines slowly decrease in length or increase in length to accomodate new files. However, when I close for example, "California", the USA rule line doesn't transition even though I have transition rules in the CSS.

How can I fix that? I tried everything under the sun for how to transition these pseudo-elements, and they transition normally, but somehow when the elements are removed, no transitions happen. The transitions only seem to be happening when I open the folder.

The relevant css for the rule lines which I want to transition is here:

```css
div.rule:before {
    content:"";
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 3px;
    height: 0;
    width: 1px;
    /* align the line exactly under the tip of the angle bracket! */
    transform: translate(1px, 2px);
    transition: all 1s;
}
    
div.rule.expanded:before {
    content:"";
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    top: 19px;
    height: auto;
    max-height: calc(100% - 23px);
    width: 1px;
    /* align the line exactly under the tip of the angle bracket! */
    transform: translate(1px, 2px);
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a working code sample

Comment: @Simp4Code Ok, I added the relevant css to the question! That is the main piece that isn't working as intended. The rest of the code is in the REPL linked above.

Comment: So you can't transition to `height: auto` the way to do it is to use `max-height` which you've basically got setup already, so you only need change `height: 0` to `max-height: 0` for `div.rule:before` and it will use the transition you've setup

Comment: You are right, when I replace `height` with `max-height` a full transition happens correctly.

Comment: Glad it's working. Been doing this for 10 years next month!!